# Stretch and shrink a div by dragging

Tags: javascript

Using javascript without jQuery, I'd like to enable a user to draw a rectangle that will tag photos. The rectangle is selected by dragging the mouse across the photo. As the user drags out the region the rectangle stretches and shrinks. The user can drag in any direction, including up and to the left, much like the draggable rectangle on most computers' desktops. What are the style attributes of a div object I should set?

---

**Edit**: I'm just looking for the right attribute to set to drag the div edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to use 
`offsetLeft`, `offsetRight`, `offsetTop`, `offsetBottom`, `offsetWidth`, and `offsetHeight` 
to get the measurements, and 
`style.left`, `style.right`, `style.top`, `style.bottom`, `style.width` and `style.height` 
to set them.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jQuery Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/).

If it fits your needs use it, otherwise have a look at how it's implemented.

Comment: jQuery is clearly the best option, but I'd like to know how to implement this without using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

there is a 'resizable' css attribute, but I think that only works from the bottom right corner... I'd suggest just listening for the mousedown event, then get the mouse coords, then start listening for mousemove events and as each one fires set the size/position of the div based on the new coords, and then on the mouseup event remove the mousemove event listener. I've done it before, I'm sure - I'll look for the code and put it in a jsfiddle for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm just looking for the right attribute to set. See the edit. I appreciate your willingness to help!

Comment: In terms of CSS properties: `top`, `left`, `width`, `height` (assuming `position: absolute` or similar).

Comment: so, `someDiv.setAttribute("style","top: _px; left: _px; width: _px; height: _px;");` where you fill in the _'s with vals.